# Iterate through objects and delete specific properties or make them undefined

Tags: javascript

I have this controller function:

```
exports.getBooks = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { ...books } = await Book.find();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

This is a current output example of the books object:

```
{
  '0': {
    _id: 60c098ef9855786e7419201d,
    author: 'J.K. Rowloing',
    title: 'Harry Potter',
    date: 1999-02-02T00:00:00.000Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  '1': {
    _id: 60c09b785f0d717012a72e3a,
    author: 'Tolkin',
    title: 'Lord of the Rings',
    date: 2009-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
    __v: 0
  },
}
```

Now before I send object to the client I want to remove the **_id** and **__v** properties from every inner object.

Making the **_id** and **__v**  properties undefined will also be fine.

I've seen some solution to this using lodash, I'm looking for a pure javascript solution.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Andreas I've tried many ways to solve this on my own for the past 3 hours using some code I found online. I figured I would ask for help instead of burning the whole day on this.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. We're here to help with problems with actual code and not to write it completely from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve the desired result.

```js
const books = {
  "0": {
    _id: "60c098ef9855786e7419201d",
    author: "J.K. Rowloing",
    title: "Harry Potter",
    date: "1999-02-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    __v: 0,
  },
  "1": {
    _id: "60c09b785f0d717012a72e3a",
    author: "Tolkin",
    title: "Lord of the Rings",
    date: "2009-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    __v: 0,
  },
};

const result = Object.entries(books).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  const { _id, __v, ...rest } = value;
  acc[key] = rest;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```